# Convert to Swift 2

Tags: objective-c, swift2, nsdateformatter

Objective-C code trying to convert to Swift 2:

```
-(void)dataLoadMethod
{
    //NSLog(@"data load method is displaying")
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH.mm"];
    NSString *strCurrentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Check float value: %.2f",[strCurrentTime floatValue]);
   if ([strCurrentTime floatValue] >= 18.00 || [strCurrentTime floatValue] <= 6.00){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NightSkin"];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
  }else{
       UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DaySkin"];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];        

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               });
```

This is my code so far in Swift:

```
func loadCreate() {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    var strCurrentTime = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
    NSLog("Check float value: %.2f", strCurrentTime)
   if ([strCurrentTime Float] >= 18.00 || [strCurrentTime Float]  <= 6.00) {
            NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DaySkin", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view);
    }
    else {
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NightSkin", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view);
    }
}
```

Having trouble from the if statement; assigning floatValue with double and presenting ViewController.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was casting `strCurrentTime` incorrectly and for some reason, you changed presenting view controller to just adding the view as a subview.

This is correctly converted code:

```
func someFunc() {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH.mm"
    let strCurrentTime = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    NSLog("Check float value: %.2f", CFloat(strCurrentTime)!)
    if CFloat(strCurrentTime)! >= 18.00 || CFloat(strCurrentTime)! <= 6.00 {
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NightSkin") as! UINavigationController)
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    } else {
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DaySkin") as! UINavigationController)
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    }
}
```

You should also use `let` instead of `var` when you have no plans in overriding or reinitializing you variable.

Comment: Thank you so very much.  I get a 'use of unresolved identifier as self' error now, however.

Comment: @Bux Where do you put this code then? I believe it should be inside some `UIViewController` where you will surely have the `self`

Comment: In Objective c I call it from:-   }
- (void)loadCreate {

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(dataLoadMethod)
                           withObject:nil];
}
- (IBAction)Wx:(id)sender {
    {
             [self loadCreate];
        
    }
    }

Comment: @Bux Are you sure you call this method inside some `UIViewController`? Like `class ViewController: UIViewController { your code... }`?

Comment: I fixed it.  Thank you.  Yep - I was calling it incorrectly. Need Coffee!

Comment: @Bux Great to hear that! Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.